# How to get a custom UITableViewCell class created in IB to load into a UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am new to this so please bear with me:

I have a .xib in IB containing a UIScrollView that has a UITableView embedded in it.  I would like to load custom UITableViewCells into the UITableView.  I have four/five custom cells created in IB but cannot get the first to load correctly.

Here are relevant screenshots from IB:

[image: .xib]
[image: custom cell "itemCell"]

I have set the class for the custom UITableViewCell created in IB to the UITableView class I created called "itemCell".  Additionally, I have connected the three text fields outlets and delegates to "itemCell".

Here is itemCell.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface itemCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *quantityTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *itemTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *priceTextField;

@end
```

Here is itemCell.m:

```
#import "itemCell.h"

@implementation itemCell
@synthesize quantityTextField,itemTextField,priceTextField;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

In filecontroller.m, which is the rootcontroller .xib's implementation file I create a new cell based on the user pressing a button (add it to an array) and then reload the tableview.  I am getting no errors but I am getting a normal cell loaded in rather than what I have created in IB. Here is rootcontroller.m.  Any help is appreciated.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    scrollView =(UIScrollView *)self.view;
    items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [items count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        return [items objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)initiateNewCell{
    itemCell *cell = [[itemCell alloc] init];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
    return cell;
}

- (IBAction)addItem:(id)sender {
    //creates the new cell to be added
    [items addObject:[self initiateNewCell]];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Are these custom cells going to be reused (displayed multiple times) or only used once within your UITableView?
Also UITableView is built on a UIScrollView, so in your situation I don't think there is need for you to put a UITableView inside a UIScrollView.

Comment: These custom cells will be displayed multiple times.  Every time the user hits the add button, ideally a new row is created and the custom cell populates it.  I think my problem may lie in the IB.  I have created a UITableViewCell outside of a viewcontroller.  Should it be inside the viewcontroller above or is that nor relevant.  Thanks for the info on the scrollview.

Comment: Just a note that class names should always start with an uppercase letter to follow standard naming conventions, so it really should be `ItemCell`. However, you also probably want to consider a more descriptive name.

Comment: thanks @MichaelMior I will do so from now on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of iOS 5 you can now load a UITableViewCell from a nib for cell reuse with the following function.

**- (void)registerNib:(UINib *)nib forCellReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier**

1. First make sure you create an IB file that contains only the UITableViewCell
2. Under Identify inspector: Set the class of the UITableViewCell to "itemCell"
   [image]
3. Under attributes inspector: Set the identifier of the UITableViewCell to "itemCellIdentifier"
   [image]
4. In viewDidLoad: place the following code, and replace itemCellNibName with the name of the nib that contains the UITableViewCell.

   ```
   NSString *myIdentifier = @"itemCellIdentifier";
   [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"itemCellNibName" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:myIdentifier];
   ```
5. In cellForRowAtIndexPath: place the following code, you can now access your IBOutlet properties you set on the itemCell, and connected in the nib.

   ```
   -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
   {
        static NSString *myIdentifier = @"itemCellIdentifier";

        itemCell *cell = (itemCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:myIdentifier];
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test Row:%i!",indexPath.row];
        return cell;
   }
   ```

Also: You do not want to include the UITableView inside a UIScrollView, a UIScrollView is already built into the UITableView, which allows for proper cell queing.

Also: I suggest you just get the bare bones of this going first, before you start pulling data from an array.

```
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
         return 10;
    }
```

Also: As someone else had mentioned, the array contains the data that will populate the UITableViewCells, not the actual cells themselves.

Comment: Thank you very much for this response.  I have one question.  For Step 4.  The only "NIB" file (I believe) in my project is ViewController.xib.  In there is a UIViewController and the UITableViewCell that I have pasted as images above.  Is the NIB filename I should use to replace @"itemCellNibName" @"ViewController"?  I have simplified the code significantly per your recommendation to get the basics down first.

Comment: Well what you will want to do is separate both of those into their own nib files. So lets go create a nib for the UITableViewCell. In the menu bar, go to file->new->file. In the pull down window that appears, select User Interface in the left column. Pick the "Empty" option. Device Family iPhone. Name it itemCellNib.
In that new nib, drag in a UITableViewCell, and follow the instructions above for it.
In the ViewController nib, delete the UITableViewCell from it.
So for the NIB filename you will put @"itemCellNib"

Comment: Thanks!  the past 30 minutes I found another site talking about creating the separate nib files - I have done so and got my code to work.  You were a great help and made what was a long frustrating day into a rewarding night.

Comment: In step 5: You need to call     if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [itemCell new];
    }
otherwise no new cells will be create if there are no cells to be reused. This should be done after the lince you try to reuse the cell. Great answer otherwise.

Comment: @Filip - Not really, the apple doc says about that method: "Prior to dequeueing any cells, call this method or the registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier: method to tell the table view how to create new cells. If a cell of the specified type is not currently in a reuse queue, the table view uses the provided information to create a new cell object automatically."

Comment: here is a great tutorial on how to do this: [briterideas.blogspot](http://briterideas.blogspot.com/2012/07/uitableview-how-to-part-4-xib-based.html)

Answer (score 3):

In your

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //This identifier string needs to be set in cell of the TableViewController in the storyboard
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    // Resuse the cell
    SomeCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // If there are no cell to be reused we create a new one
    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [SomeCustomCell new];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    NSString *someString = [yourArrayWithStringsOrWhatEver objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Setting the some property of your custom cell
   [cell.yourSpecificCellProperty someString];

   [cell.yourOtherSpecificCellProperty setText:@"What Ever your want!"];
}
```

Your cell's properties could be whatever your have connected to your custom cell in interface builder.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Well there are a few things that aren't right:

- The class name begins with upper case letter `itemCell` -> `ItemCell`
- You should reuse the cell. The way you want to do this, you will create a separate cell for each index path.
- the `items` array should only contain the data source of your table, not your cells
- instead of calling reload data, you can add just one row to the table, and it can be animated too

Try something like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    scrollView =(UIScrollView *)self.view;
    items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [items count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"itemCell" owner:self options:nil].lastObject;
        cell.reuseIdentifier = CellIdentifier;
    }

    // Do any additional setup to the cell

    return cell;
}

- (IBAction)addItem:(id)sender {
    [items addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:items.count]]; // Here comes the data source
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:items.count - 1 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

PS: I wrote it without an IDE so there might be some errors

Comment: Thanks alot for the response. The remaining issues are:            1)'cell.reuseIdentifier = CellIdentifier;' is giving me the error: "assignment to readonly property".                                 2) When clicking "add" I get another error about "invalid number of rows".  It appears the resulting number of rows is still 0 when it should be 1.  Any ideas?                                    Additionally - I am confused about this line: cell = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"itemCell" owner:self options:nil].lastObject;  Is the single UITableViewCell in IB considered a nib?

Comment: You can't do `cell.reuseIdentifier = CellIdentifier`. Instead, set the reuse identifier in the `itemCell` NIB.

Comment: Sorry about the reuse id, Michael's right, set it from the nib. About the error, without running your code, I don`t know what is wrong with it. And a nib is a file wit XIB extension, you should create for your `itemCell` a separate nib file.