# Multiple rounded-corner rows per UITableView section

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview

I know that if I create a `UITableView` with grouped sections and one row per section, then I will get each row with rounded corners, but I need more than one row per section, with each row still having rounded corners. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can manipulate the Cell's CALayer property

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

[cell.layer setCornerRadius:5.0f];
[cell.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[cell.layer setBorderWidth:2.0f];
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case you would have to provide a custom `UITableViewCell` implementation, that is shaped with round edges. Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you will have to init and use your own, customised cell.

This [so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14086855/how-to-get-a-custom-uitableviewcell-class-created-in-ib-to-load-into-a-uitablevi) discusses how to create a custom `UITableViewCell`.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own custome uitableview cell and make its corner rounded by using its layer property.